# php array empty when returned without referencing an index

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP which gathers data from the DB and places each row into an array which it then places in a final array which is returned to the JavaScript:

```
$active = /*some SQL statement*/
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $active);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $value = array( 
        "id"=>$row["quest"],
        "received"=>$row["received"]
    );

    array_push($data, $value);
}

return json_encode($data);
```

I know that the SQL statement is working and that `$value` has values in it, but the array returned to the JavaScript page is always an empty string instead of a JSON object.

If I place my return statement inside my `while` loop, then the data is returned:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $value = array( 
        "id"=>$row["quest"],
        "received"=>$row["received"]
    );

    array_push($data, $value);
    return json_encode($data);

}
```

But obviously this does not return the data as I want it, after the loop has completed.

And if I change my return statement to:

```
return json_encode($data[1]);
```

Then the data is also returned.

Please help me figure this one out.

Comment: Is this a function?? If not use `echo` and not `return`

Comment: Would have been useful to add that to the code you provided

Comment: return json_encode($data);
this line should be outside the while loop

Comment: Mixing mysqli with mysql at `MYSQL_ASSOC`

Comment: Also use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` and not `MYSQL_ASSOC` I am pretty sure this should be producing some sort of error message are you looking at php error log. Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: But even this doesn't work: `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: The error report returns nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changed code

```
$active = /*some SQL statement*/
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $active);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $value = array( 
        "id"=>$row["quest"],
        "received"=>$row["received"]
    );
   $data[]=$value; // this is trick 
}

return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: MYSQLI_ASSOC and not MYSQL_ASSOC

Comment: This just returns an empty array like so: `[ ]`

Comment: @ALR Can you try with remove MYSQLI_ASSOC as a paramer?

Comment: It returns a blank string still

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$value = array( 
    "id"=>$row["quest"],
    "received"=>$row["received"]
);

array_push($data, $value);

}

return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: MYSQLI_ASSOC and not MYSQL_ASSOC

Comment: No, still returns an empty string

Comment: print_r($value); array_push($data, $value); check $value is empty or not

Comment: `print_r($data)` displays the data perfectly. So why does it not work when I try to send the array?